# Calculating a line's normal for the purposes of collision

Tags: physics

Given a line defined as two points in screen coordinate space (which themselves are two 2D vector positions) how would I calculate a 2D Vector perpendicular in the "up" direction for determining a normal force?

Comment: The normal is not consistently defined if what you have is just a pair of __(A,B)__ points. But you can choose one in your 2D plane, e.g. the one pointing at the left w.r.t to your BA vector.

Comment: @Casey, check this link for a solution: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/367293-finding-the-normal-to-a-2d-line/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a vector *v* = A - B (the direction is from B to A), then you need to find a vector *u* so that *dot(u,v) = 0*.

If *v=(x,y)*, there's no unique solution for this problem, but let's choose the normal pointing to the left side of the *v* vector. This one is *u=(-y,x)* and it is attained by rotating *v* by 90 degrees. Using complex numbers: *v = x +  i y* and a rotation of 90 degrees means multiplying *v* by **i**. Hence *u*= *vi* = *i x - y* or in cartesian coordinates: *u=(-y,x)*.